# Python Pose Estimation Example Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

**I'm beginner at opencv and I'm trying to run tutorial codes at:** http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_table_of_contents_calib3d/py_table_of_contents_calib3d.html

My code and problem:

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

# data comes from calibration program same as tutorial
data=scipy.io.loadmat('distm.mat')
dist=data['dist000']
mtx=data['mtx']
data=None

#takes the corners in the chessboard  
def draw(img, corners, imgpts):
    corner = tuple(corners[0].ravel())
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[0].ravel()), (255,0,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[1].ravel()), (0,255,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[2].ravel()), (0,0,255), 5)
    return img

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

axis = np.float32([[3,0,0], [0,3,0], [0,0,-3]]).reshape(-1,3)

# cam open and wait a second to deny black or dark images                                                                              
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
ret, frame = cap.read()
print "Checking camera read:"+str(ret)
while ret ==False:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
time.sleep(1)

# takes live photos from camera
for i in range(0,20):
    print i

    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7,6),None)
    print ret

    if ret == True:

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        # 'corners2' returns "none" and below codes not working so I use 'corners'
        print corners2
        # Find the rotation and translation vectors.
        rvecs, tvecs, inliers = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners, mtx, dist)

        # project 3D points to image plane
        imgpts, jac = cv2.projectPoints(axis, rvecs, tvecs, mtx, dist)

        img = draw(img,corners,imgpts)  # img returns None
        print img                       
        cv2.imshow('pose',img)           # error line 
        k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff
```

**and gives error at "cv2.imshow('pose',img)" as:**

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in
cv::imshow, file ..\..\..\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 269
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
<module>   File
"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)   File "C:/Users/ACS/Documents/Python/Pose Estimation.py", line 49, in
<module>
    cv2.imshow('pose',img) cv2.error: ..\..\..\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:269: error: (-215)
size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that may cause trouble is the fact that the success of `cap.read()` is not checked : the variable `ret` is re-assigned to a new value without having been checked the first time.

Surrounding the code below the `cap.read()` with another `if ret:` may help. You will notice there's no need for `== True` in Python

Comment: to draw 3d pose axes on the img "draw"  function  which defined above isnt working? or wrong code

Comment: You're right, I should have pointed to opencv 3 documentation, and in this version `cv2.line` does return the image. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have insert this code but no change
                                                                                          
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print "Checking camera read:"+str(ret)
    while ret ==False:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
        ret, frame = cap.read()
    time.sleep(1)

Comment: Well I'll have to leave that up to you then, after some debugging you should be able to find why that img is None (or of size 0). If not, come back with a more [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Arnaud's interest.

I fix the problem. Working code:

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

data=scipy.io.loadmat('distm.mat')
dist=data['dist000']
mtx=data['mtx']
data=None

#takes the corners in the chessboard 
def draw(img, corners, imgpts):
    corner = tuple(corners[0].ravel())
    cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[0].ravel()), (255,0,0), 5)
    cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[1].ravel()), (0,255,0), 5)
    cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[2].ravel()), (0,0,255), 5)
    return img

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

axis = np.float32([[3,0,0], [0,3,0], [0,0,-3]]).reshape(-1,3)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
ret, frame = cap.read()
print "Checking camera read:"+str(ret)
while ret ==False:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
time.sleep(1)

for i in range(0,20):
    time.sleep(1)
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7,6),None)
    print str(i)+"'th image check board corners "+str(ret)
    if ret :
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        print corners2
        # Find the rotation and translation vectors.
        rvecs, tvecs, inliers = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners, mtx, dist)

        # project 3D points to image plane
        imgpts, jac = cv2.projectPoints(axis, rvecs, tvecs, mtx, dist)

        img = draw(img,corners,imgpts)
        cv2.imshow('pose',img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff
```